# Ray Sphere Intersection

Tags: geometry

I'm reading a book on raytracing and there's a part where the author is working out the equation for ray-sphere intersection. There's a part I don't understand that I'm hoping I can get help with.
The equation starts with:

$(\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{c}) \bullet (\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{c}) - r^2 = 0$

Bold values are vectors, and the dot indicates the dot product.

He then substitutes the ray in for **p**, making the equation:

$(\mathbf{o} + t \mathbf{d} - \mathbf{c}) \bullet (\mathbf{o} + t \mathbf{d} - \mathbf{c}) - r^2 = 0$

Next is the part I couldn't follow. He expands the equation to:

$(\mathbf{d} \bullet \mathbf{d})t^2 + [2(\mathbf{o} - \mathbf{c}) \bullet \mathbf{d}]t + (\mathbf{o} - \mathbf{c}) \bullet (\mathbf{o} - \mathbf{c}) - r^2 = 0$

I know it's kind of a stupid question, but can someone break it down how he got from equation 2 to equation 3 by expanding? I can't figure out all the intermediate steps on my own.

Comment: write $q = o - c,$ then $(q + td)\cdot (q + t d) = r^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of rearranging the terms inside and applying FOIL:

$$(\mathbf{o} + t \mathbf{d} - \mathbf{c}) \cdot (\mathbf{o} + t \mathbf{d} - \mathbf{c}) \\ = [t \mathbf{d} + (\mathbf{o} - \mathbf{c})] \cdot [t \mathbf{d} + (\mathbf{o} - \mathbf{c})] \\ = t^2 \mathbf{d} \cdot \mathbf{d} + 2t (\mathbf{o} - \mathbf{c}) \cdot \mathbf{d} + (\mathbf{o} - \mathbf{c}) \cdot (\mathbf{o} - \mathbf{c}).$$

Going from the first line to the second, I used the fact that addition and subtraction with vectors are each commutative:  $\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{a}.$

Going from the second line to the third, I used the fact that the dot product of two vectors is commutative:  $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{a}.$

Also "FOIL" for the dot product of the vector sums:

$$(\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b}) \cdot (\mathbf{c} + \mathbf{d}) = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c} + \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{d} + \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c} + \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{d}.$$